# Do DLC weapons count against the need to have all weapons to unlock the Master Sword seal?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

On the Master Sword, to begin unlocking the seal, you have to have collected all weapons. With the Master Quest DLC, I can now get more weapons for Volga and so forth. Do those count? Have I made my task harder by installing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, they do not. Having installed Master Quest, I then completed unlocking all the weapons in the Adventure Mode standard map (whew!) and the Master Sword's seal turned red, indicating that it was now counting down. Yay for me!